# jQuery each function: not properly getting data as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason, I cannot obtain the text/html from the 2nd TD as specified below

The template tags are Django.

```
{% block content %}
{% if host.host_scripts %}
<table class="table">
  <button class="btn btn-info add" id="{{forloop.counter}}">Add to session</button>
  {% for script in host.host_scripts %}
     <tr>
        <td id="script-name-{{forloop.counter}}">{{script.scriptName}}</td>
        <td id="script-output-{{forloop.counter}}">{{script.scriptOutput|linebreaks}}</td>
     </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
<script>
$(".add").click(function(e) {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   scriptList = []
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#myTable-"+id+" tr ").each(function() {
       var name = $(this).find('#script-name-'+id).html();
       var output = $(this).find('#script-output-'+id).html();
       var myList = [name, output];
       console.log('Name -> ' + name);
       console.log('Output -> ' + output);
       scriptList.push(myList);
   });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I can get the name variable just fine. For some reason I cannot get the scriptOutput variable.

I assumed this was due to `|linebreaks`  but removing it has no influence on the behavior.

**Desired behavior:**

Per tr in the table, get the contents of the td's and add to the list.

**Current behavior:**

It only get's the name variable, skips the scriptOutput variable for some reason.

I managed to get 'some' output, now I get the same value returned for output for every scriptName. I'm baffled as I can't see what's wrong with the ID's.

```
{% block content %}
{% if host.host_scripts %}
<table class="table myTable">
  <button class="btn btn-info add" id="{{forloop.counter}}">Add to session</button>
  {% for script in host.host_scripts %}
     <tr>
        <td id="script-name-{{forloop.counter}}">{{script.scriptName}}</td>
        <td id="script-output-{{forloop.counter}}">{{script.scriptOutput|linebreaks}}</td>
     </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
<script>
var scriptList = []

$("#myTable-"+id+" tr").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).find('td:first').html();
    var output = $('#script_output-'+id).html();
    var script = [name, output];
    scriptList.push(script);
    console.log('Text: ' + output);
});
console.log(scriptList);
</script>
```

I am aware I should probably expand my ID to something of sorts:

```
<td id="script-output-{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}-{{forloop.counter}}">{{script.scriptOutput|linebreaks}}</td>
```

Yet I can't seem to figure it out, what am I doing wrong??

Comment: I doubt you would get either, you're missing the `-` between `script-name`/`script-output` and the `id`

Comment: typo: your `id`s are `script-output-N`, but you're querying `#script-outputN` (no hyphen).

Comment: Also, you should either tag the question with whatever language/framework you use that uses those `{%...%}`and `{{...}}` substitutions, or provide the HTML/JS as it looks **after** the substitution.

Comment: The hyphen was a typo, my apologies. I have corrected the code as requested.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
<script>
$(".add").click(function(e) {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   scriptList = []
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#myTable-"+id+" tr ").each(function(index, el) {
       var name = $(el).find('#script-name-'+id).html();
       var output = $(el).find('#script-output-'+id).html();
       var myList = [name, output];
       console.log('Name -> ' + name);
       console.log('Output -> ' + output);
       scriptList.push(myList);
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: _"Iterating over elements does not change the value of `this`"_ - [yes it does](http://api.jquery.com/each/): _"the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element."_

Comment: The one you've linked to isn't the same `each` method.  It says as much in that page: _"The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each()"_

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. `this` is indeed referring to the value argument of the callback functions as indicated in the jQuery Docs. https://api.jquery.com/each/